# Google Cloud Function Build failed. Error ID: 99f2b037

Tags: python, pip, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

Build failed when I try to update code and re-deploy the Google Cloud Function.

Deploy Script:

```
gcloud functions deploy <my-func-name> --entry-point <my-entry-point> \
--runtime python37 \
--trigger-http \
--region=asia-east2 \
--memory=8192 \
--timeout=540
```

Error Message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: 
/layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'pip' 
(AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__file__'); Error ID: 99f2b037
```

Source code structure:

```
.
├── lib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── azsync.py
├── main.py
└── requirements.txt
```

Requirements.txt:

```
flask==1.0
gcsfs==0.4.0
pandas==0.25.0
azure-storage-blob==12.0.0
```

Comment: Is this working [locally](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/running/overview#local_testing). Also please provide a [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The release of setuptools  60.3.0 caused AttributeError because of a [bug](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3002) and now [Setuptools](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3002) 60.3.1 [is available](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html). You can refer to the GitHub Link [here](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/actions/runs/1663735382).

For more information you can refer to the [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70619556/15774176) as :

> If you run into this pip error in a Cloud Function, you might consider updating pip in the "`requirements.txt`" but if you are in such an unstable Cloud Function the better workaround seems to be to create a new Cloud Function and copy everything in there.
>
> The pip error probably just shows that the source script, in this case the `requirements.txt`, cannot be run since the source code is not fully embedded anymore or has lost some embedding in the Google Storage.
> or you give that Cloud Function a second chance and edit, go to Source tab, click on Dropdown Source code to choose Inline Editor and add main.py and requirements.txt manually (Runtime: Python).”

Comment: @EEEEH Posted an answer, is it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

With the provided requirements.txt and the gcloud deploy command, I deployed a sample Cloud Function, and it worked fine.

So, I believe the issue is with one of your .py code files.

To troubleshoot further, you can go to the below URL:

https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=asia-east2?project=<PROJECT_ID>

And then select the failed Build to browse its logs, and view the error message in detail.